# React.ref prop in interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried putting string as the ref but I get an warning when I try to use ref?.current

```
Property 'current' does not exist on type 'string'
```

What should be used for ref prop in the interface. I don;t know what the ref type would be upfront. It could be HTMLInputElement it could be a div basically it could be any element.

```
interface IProps {
 name: string,
 time: number
 ref?: string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript won't let you pass a generic (as in: not known in advance) `React.Ref<HTMLElement>` or `React.Ref<Element>`.

You need to trick the type checker to accept your ref by using `any`.

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  time: number;
  ref?: React.Ref<any>;
}
```

Keep in mind that this solution is not entirely type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Ref in React  is generally described by the following interface: `React.Ref<HTMLInputElement>`.

Try:

```
interface IProps {
 name: string,
 time: number
 ref?: React.Ref<HTMLInputElement>
}
```

Comment: Right but what if the ref is not a HTMLInputElement ? As I said it could be anything.

Comment: Then opt for something like `React.Ref<HTMLInputElement | HTMLElement | string | any>`, this is not that type-safe, but still.